# Replacing Chrome OS on ASUS Chromebook C202S with Ubuntu and run it as the primary OS

Tags: system-installation, chromebook

I have ASUS Chromebook C202S running on Chrome OS and I want to replace it with Ubuntu and run it as the primary OS.

I only found the thing with the developer mode to dual boot Linux, but I want to remove Chrome OS completely and only run Ubuntu.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

*************edited to get keyboard working*******************

I have successfully stripped(mostly) chromeOS. I still get the chrome warning screen at boot, but legacy booting (ctrl+l) SEAbios will let me boot Ubuntu from the local storage. Unfortunately I cannot get my laptop keyboard working but USB works fine. I am tracing down a fix for this that involves getting into the bios menu but have not had a chance to get to try it.

Get SeaBios for Chromebook from: https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/.

This link has complete instructions on the bios install. Part of the instructions requires you to remove a jumper screw from the motherboard. iFixit has great [documentation on accessing the mother board.](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Asus+Chromebook+C202+Motherboard+Replacement/74103) The jumper screw is on the upper left hand side of the mobo. If you look by the left usb port you will see a screw on the mobo with two copper pads on each side of it. Remove this screw to remove the jumper. 
[Picture showing mobo write block jumper](https://edgeup.asus.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/motherboard.jpg), notice in upper left hand side a screw hole with arrow pointing to it and two copper semi circles around the screw hole.

*****NOTE: Remove Jumper first, before doing Bios install********

Once jumper is removed, login to chromeOS and do the Bios install.
Once bios is installed you will be able to boot from USB.
Now you need to create a usb drive that will let you install linux.

To do this download the latest ubuntu iso on another pc. On that same pc install the Chromebook Recovery Utility. And follow [these](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/use-chromebook-recovery-utility-troubleshooting/) instructions for Alternate install to install ubuntu on the USB drive.

Once installed on usb you can start the install of ubuntu to your chromebook.

Put usb in chromebook and turn on the chromebook.

On OS Verification warning screen press ctrl+l to go to SeaBios.

In Seabios, boot from the USB.

You should see a trying to install a GFXgui. It will fail.

You should now see "boot: ". when you see this type "help" and hit enter.

It will generate another menu, and then after menu is done loading. Hit enter and Ubuntu should start installing. Enjoy!

These instructions were written while I was away from my home office so I may have missed something.

****************how to get the keyboard working*********************************

So....the legacy bios from johnlewis is great but it is Legacy bios. We want UEFI bios in order to have better functionality. So we want to use the bios from [MrChromebox.tech](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript). If you have followed all the directions above, then you will already have ubuntu installed. So go into terminal and you will need to install curl, if you dont have it and try to use "curl" the terminal will tell you how to download it. Follow the instructions on MrChromebox website. Its easy peasy (espicially if you already wiped chrome).

Note: I was not able to get ubuntu working again after installing UEFI bios(there is a fix in the FAQ but it did not work for me). So I am reinstalling ubuntu since my old image was a default image. It would be a more cleaner process to start with the UEFI bios from MrChromebox. This firmaware lets you scrub out even more remnants of ChromeOS. I think this is as best as it will get.